# How to position text over an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I center a text over an image in css?

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="sample.png"/>
    <div class="text">
       <h2>Some text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to do something like the one below but I'm having difficulties, here's my current css

```
<style>
.image {
   position: relative;
}

h2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 300px;
   height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

When I use background-image I do not get any output from html2pdf:

```
<style>
#image_container{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 700px;
    background-image:url('switch.png');
}
</style>
<a href="prints.php">Print</a>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div id="image_container"></div>
<?php 
$_SESSION['sess'] = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_flush();
?>
```

Here's prints.php:

```
<?php require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php'); ?>
<?php
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L', 'A4', 'en');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($_SESSION['sess']);
$html2pdf->Output('random.pdf');
?>
```

Comment: it is possibl to make it with a background image ?

Comment: This make overlay effect in image

Answer (score 198, accepted):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EgLKV/3/

Its done by using `position:absolute` and `z-index` to place the text over the image.

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 150px;
  top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg" />
  <p id="text">
    Hello World!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could avoid the z-index

Comment: @danielad: It was working fine until you edited the answer. I've rolled back your edits.

Comment: haah-- thank me i just remind you to fix things up --it was not working yesterday - vene the hello world text

Comment: How could you get the text in the middle of the image? Left 200, bottom 200?

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield Yes, just fiddle around with the left and bottom values to move the text around

Comment: Sadly this ends up being a really bad option if you want your site to follow modern, responsive practices as you're fixing the size of the container (the answer was from 2012 so its understandably out of date). A much better solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333495/text-over-image-responsive

Answer (score 33):

This is another method for working with responsive sizes. It will keep your text centered and maintain its position within its parent. If you don't want it centered then it's even easier, just work with the `absolute` parameters. Keep in mind the main container is using `display: inline-block`. There are many others ways to do this, depending on what you're working on.

Based off of [Centering the Unknown](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

[Working codepen example here](http://codepen.io/rtro92/pen/VjzdPA)

**HTML**

```
<div class="containerBox">
    <div class="text-box">
        <h4>Your Text is responsive and centered</h4>
    </div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x100"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.containerBox {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
.text-box {
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;    
   width: 100%;
}
.text-box:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
h4 {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px; /*or whatever you want*/
   color: #FFF;   
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not set `sample.png` as background image of `text` or `h2` css class? This will give effect as you have written over an image.

Comment: What if the image needs to be a semantic part of the document?

Comment: @animuson: I don't think this is the case in here. :\

Comment: I'm using html2pdf to generate a pdf from it and if I use background-image I do not get anything.

Comment: @KyokaSuigetsu : then you should change question title to contain that you are using html2pdf.

Answer (score 8):

For a responsive design it is good to use a container having a relative layout and content (placed in container) having fixed layout as.

**CSS Styles:**

```
/*Centering element in a base container*/

.contianer-relative{ 
  position: relative;
 }

.content-center-text-absolute{ 
  position: absolute; 
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 51;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<!-- Have used ionic classes -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col remove-padding contianer-relative"><!-- container with position relative -->
        <div class="item item-image clear-border" ><a href="#"><img ng-src="img/engg-manl.png" alt="ENGINEERING MANUAL" title="ENGINEERING MANUAL" ></a></div> <!-- Image intended to work as a background -->
        <h4 class="content-center-text-absolute white-text"><strong>ENGINEERING <br> MANUALS</strong></h4><!-- content div with position fixed -->
    </div>
    <div class="col remove-padding contianer-relative"><!-- container with position relative -->
        <div class="item item-image clear-border"><a href="#"><img ng-src="img/contract-directory.png" alt="CONTRACTOR DIRECTORY" title="CONTRACTOR DIRECTORY"></a></div><!-- Image intended to work as a background -->
        <h4 class="content-center-text-absolute white-text"><strong>CONTRACTOR <br> DIRECTORY</strong></h4><!-- content div with position fixed -->
    </div>       
</div>
```

For IONIC Grid layout, evenly spaced grid elements and the classes used in above HTML, please refer - [Grid: Evenly Spaced Columns](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-even). Hope it helps you out... :)

Answer (score 4):

as Harry Joy points out, set the image as the div's background and then, if you only have one line of text you can set the line-height of the text to be the same as the div height and this will place your text in the center of the div.

If you have more than one line you'll want to set the display to be table-cell and vertical-alignment to middle.

Comment: I'm using html2pdf to create a pdf from those. I do not see any image if I use a background-image. Please see my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what html2pdf is.

Answer (score 3):

as of 2017 this is more responsive and worked for me.
This is for putting text inside vs over, like a badge.
instead of the number 8, I had a variable to pull data from a database.

this code started with [Kailas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1904479/kailas)'s answer up above

https://jsfiddle.net/jim54729/memmu2wb/3/

```css
.containerBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.dataNumber {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerBox">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s20.postimg.org/huun8e6fh/Gold_Ring.png">
  <div class='text-box'>
    <p class='dataNumber'> 8 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small and short way of doing the same:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  color: white;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/600') no-repeat;
  background-size: 250px 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <p>
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <h5>Heading 5</h5>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Headings have no business inside a paragraph. It's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: Set `position: relative;` on the container element and set `position: absolute;` on child elements in that container element, with the necessary `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`-adjusting parameters:

```css
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 2px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    float:left;color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container" style="">
    
        <img src="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png" width="100">
        <div class="top-left">Wikipedia</div>
        <div class="bottom-right">Everyone's Encyclopedia</div>
    
    </div>
```

Center it directly in the middle with the following CSS...

```
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```