# How to align text over an Image in a responsive webpage

Tags: html, css, image, responsiveness

This is not a duplicate as I am talking about responsive websites

This is the header I want and I would like it to be responsive.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0PzJ.jpg)

However Instead of using it as an Image I would like to have the image and text separate. here is the original image file
[original image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGpzd.jpg)

The Header image currently scales correctly for a responsive page however I would like the text positioned over the image like in my first image and have it scale according to the device the user uses.

I would like to accomplish this using html and css only.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
 <img src="images/Header.jpeg" alt=""/>
 <h1>Mark Osullivan</h1>
 <h2>Wedding Photograpgy </h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1024px;
}   

#header h1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
 font-size: 50px;
}

#header h2 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
 font-size: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this output r u expecting

check the output in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/guwujef/edit?html,css)

```css
#header img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
#header h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
   text-align:center;
 
}
#header h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
  font-size: 35px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGpzd.jpg" />
    <h1>Mark Osullivan</h1>
    <h2>Wedding Photograpgy </h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Correct but I would also Like the size of the text to scale with the image.

Comment: can u explain more

Comment: and thank you for the repy

Comment: in my example image the size of the text scales according to what device you use, check it out and resize your browser window and you will see what I mean

Comment: check this link might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744177/scaling-text-and-image-in-css

Comment: Yea I think the best solution is to use an image with the text already on it,

Answer (score 0):

Id go with the one above too. Use your image as a background and put the text in the div on the top

Oh and to scale your text just make the font size in vw or em. 
However in my exp ive gotten away with just using pixels to specify font size and just have the size change in media queries as you go down.

Hope that helps

Comment: I agree with changing the size of the text in px according to media queries, the answer you agreed with is half working, the only problem now is adjusting the height of the background image as the device screen size gets smaller

Comment: Okay so set the height of the div in vw too.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the image as the background of the `header` and align your text in the `center`

```css
#header  {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1024px;
 background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGpzd.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}   

#header h1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
 font-size: 50px;
}

#header h2 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #000000;
 font-size: 35px;
}
#header h1, #header h2{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
 
 <h1>Mark Osullivan</h1>
 <h2>Wedding Photograpgy </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that, however the image does not respond to the device size correctly, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @MarkOsullivan can you please check it now! I have updated the code for you.
thank you!

Comment: its getting there thank you, The image is scaling horizontally but its staying at the same height no-matter my screen size, thank you for the help