# Can multiple imgs form an image background?

Tags: html, css

[Be so kind as to look at this theme here](http://themeforest.net/item/biosphere-environmental-charity-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/5409397). Look at that block of people's faces in the footer, faded, behind the 'create a nice banner like this with a few simple clicks' text. **Can this effect be achieved with multiple img tags?**

Now, the way they've done it is simple. They literally have one image of all of those cropped faces which they've set to 20% opacity in photoshop and simply set that as the background image of the div. I want to do the same effect, but with database-derived images, so that approach is useless to me.

So can I do the exact same effect, but through multiple img tags? Something that will work in IE 7,8,9? Something to do with z-indexes, perhaps?

Comment: `img` elements usually make poor choices for a "background". Consider simply layering multiple (non image) elements, such as stacked divs, placing *all* the foreground content on them, and then using the CSS background property with appropriate offsets .. I have no idea what games are required for outdated rendering engines.

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiple image tags with CSS's `opacity` to do it. Something like this:

HTML

```
<img src="..." />
<img src="..." />
...
```

CSS

```
img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Y5Qg/

You might have to use [some tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/) for older versions of IE, but all modern browsers will support this just fine.

Comment: Not quite, text needs to appear above it, as in the theme forest example.. http://jsfiddle.net/6Y5Qg/1/

Comment: Then you'll want to use `z-index` and absolute positioning to do that. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css

Comment: From the performance perspective I would consider pre-generating the faces background-image on the server. Sending many requests will cost You time. Specially if You keep alive is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Stacking divs would be the easiest... here's and example:

```
<style>

#wrap {}

#imgWrap {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index:1;

}

#imgWrap img {
    float: left;
    }

#container {
    color: white;
    margin-top: -200px; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 200px; 
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: black}

#container h1 {
    margin: 0;
    color: white; 
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
}

</style>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="imgWrap">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
        <img src="http://mymobileengagement.com/images/social-icons/pinterest/pintrest.png">
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```