# Placing a text over an image with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing a title text and an image.

With the code below, the title is showing just above the image.

HTML code:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="text">
  <center>Heading</center>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
  <img src="sample.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to align the title so that it will appear on the center (vertically and horizontally) of the image.

How can I achieve that using HTML and CSS?

Comment: The `center` element is deprecated and you shouldn't use it.

Comment: You can find the answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css

Comment: It make align horizontally center. I want to align it vertically middle. @JamesDonnelly

Comment: @user3392772 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation you can center the text horizontally by applying css to text div

Comment: @user3392772 You may want to accept one of the answers as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is mostly correct with the exception of using the `center` element and you do not need to wrap the `img` element in a `div.`

Here is some example markup:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <img src="sample.png">
</div>
```

And its corresponding CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
  position:relative;
}
.thumbnail h1 {
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;top:50%;left:0;width:100%;
  margin-top:-20px; /*make the negative top margin = half your h1 element height */
}
```

You could always use an element other than an h1 to hold your title. This just depends on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the image tag and make the image be the background of the container div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="text">
    Heading
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
    background-image: url('sample.jpg');
    text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT:** I don't want to sell it as my perfect answer, but I realized I missed the vertical alignment, and as similar solutions have already been provided here in comments and answers, let me just provide you with a good source of info below. The point is that you could use `vertical-align:middle` if you used `span` or other inline element, but with `div`, you have to use other tricks like `position:absolute` and minus margins.

Source: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: i cannot use this. Because the image always changes. There are lot such thumbnails... (done using PHP)

Comment: like I said, there are other options, check out my link or the answers others gave...

Comment: sorry i didn't got it

Comment: sorry, what did you not get?

Comment: the thing has to be responsive too... the answer i marked got it worked @webeno

Comment: well, I'm happy you got your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following might help you.

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="text">
         Heading
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    background-image: url('http://cs616623.vk.me/v616623331/7991/vPKjXbo-c7o.jpg');
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    line-height: 240px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

Take into account that in this approach you would have to set manually the `height` and the `width` of your `text` element. Moreover, the `height` should be duplicated in the `line-height` in order for vertical alignment to work correctly.

You could test and change the code in the corresponding [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danek/MMr83/) or just check the [full-screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/danek/MMr83/embedded/result/).

Comment: i cannot put the image in css. Because the image url changes for different thumbnails

Comment: Oh, I see! Please, consider adding these details to your question in order to make it more specific. That way you will receive the answers in a shorter manner :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using lineheight to vertically align the text(as some answers suggest) solely because if the header is to long and spans over across two rows it would look terrible.

What I would do is to absolute position the heading and then use `display: table-cell` to vertical align it.

**Note** that to be able to use this solution you have to specify an height for the heading.

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="text">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .thumbnail{
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
}
.text{
    position:absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 350px;
}
.text h1{
    height: 250px; 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;  
    width: 350px; 
    color: #fff;
}
```

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn9Hd/1/)