# Placing a div with background color over slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to display products for an e-commerce application:

This is what want to achieve:

[image]

This is what I am getting:

[image]

**My Code:**

```
<div>
  <a href="#" >
   <img src="img/offers/1.jpg" class="u-max-full-width"  />
   <div class="one">
      <p>30%</p>
   </div>
  </a>
</div>

.one{
  color:black; 
  background-color:red !important;
  width:30%;
  text-align:center; 
  border-radius:10%;
  margin-top:-50px;
}
```

I went through this solution here ([How to position text over an image in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css)) however, in my case I won't be able to use absolute position for the content. Edited Fiddle link from the above ans http://jsfiddle.net/utpalnu/EgLKV/5234/

My Fiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/utpalnu/rdfg2fsk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to add this to your CSS.

```
position:relative
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkyuyvo7/

Comment: oh my!! Wasted a hell of a time after this..Indeed a silly mistake ..  :(  thanks a ton..

Comment: Umm, it doesn't work properly. Red label's width is 30% of **whole** page width. You may have issues when you will place multiple boxes side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `position:relative` to wrapping element and then you can use `position:absolute` to the red label.

```
.wrapper { //add this class to <a> tag
 position:relative;
}
.one {
    color:black; 
    background-color: red;
    width:30%;
    text-align:center; 
    border-radius:10%;
    position:absolute; // now it will work.
    top: -30px; //changed from margin to "top" style, but margin will also work.
    left: 10px; // I've also added "left" for nice look :)

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rdfg2fsk/3/