# Text over the image/button

Tags: xml, html, css

How to make text over the image/button using html/css.

Eg: I have a button(Login Button). I want the text "Login" to be placed over that button. The text should be center of the image/button.

Comment: You can have a div with background image and content as Login which can be aligned in center position.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

HTML Code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="myButton"/>
```

CSS:

```
.myButton {
    background-color:#44c767;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the image (which was the issue)?

Comment: @jbutler Question asked for Button Or Image.FYI: Read the question again.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply set the `background-image` property of the relevant `button` (or other element if you are using in place of a `button`).

Note that you can control height/vertical centering of the text using `line-height`, however, if the text is multi-line this may have other issues, so you may wish to resort to using `padding`, or a sub element with `top:50%;tranform:translateY(-50%);`

If using a semantically valid `button` element, text is center aligned by default, otherwise simply set `text-align:center`

```css
button {
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
button.imgButton {
  color: white;
  background-image: url(http://abdpbt.com/tech/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/gradient.jpg);
  background-size:cover; /* <-- scale the image to cover the button */
  background-position:center center; /* <-- center the image in the button */
}
```

```html
<button>Normal Button</button>

<button class='imgButton'>Image Button</button>
```

Comment: much cleaner than my approach :)

Comment: @SW4 OP needs to align the text on button, I don't think there will be solution required for multiline. then button element doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @KheemaPandey: There are many reasons why text on a button may overlap, which would be affected by `line-height` (as SW4 has mentioned)

Comment: @jbutler483 you didn't understand what i am saying..Does Button have really a multiline text.... Atleast  what i understood button should be user focused because they push User to perform any action.. so short text is better option.

Comment: @KheemaPandey: yes, button elements do support multilined text? Are you possibly mixing up with `<input type="text"/>`? There are many cases where text might want to be wrapped. consider a 'narrow' button: like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/hsjfe4ze/), for example

Comment: I know button support multiline text, but for end user to things clear and perform a better `call to action` button text should be short.

Comment: @jbutler483 In past we all faced same situation when we use a background image for button and with long text its break..I am not against the solution.. just want to share to improved the overall user experience the text should be short and effective..

Comment: I guess I am going on now off-topic.. excuse me if I am making a nonsense arguments.

Comment: @KheemaPandey, note that for semantic purposes, `button` should be used where possible for a button

Answer (score 0):

## Centering in front of an image

If you need to center text over an image, you might want to wrap your `img` in a div, use positioning on the `img` itself as well as the text.

You would then be able to center this using transforms (supporting multi-lined text).

**demo**

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: tomato;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" />
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

---

## Images with buttons

Since button elements are centered automatically by default, you're issue would be to add an image to the button.

This can be achieved using the `background-image` property.

So in your CSS use something like:

```
background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
```

adjusting the size using

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

to stretch it to the full size of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the text between the button tags.
In CSS, select the button and do something like this

```
#button {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the image (which was the issue)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find your code

take a look at bootstrap framework as well

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2nhc26/

```
<div class="button">
    Button
</div>

.button {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#000000;
    width 100%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: again, this has nothing to do with the image (which was the issue)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It will take centre alignment by default.

```
<button type="button">This is Button</button>
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the image (which was the issue)?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can have a div with background image.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Login
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    background-image:url("http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg");
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uf9c0x6/)

Answer (score -1):

How about using a table?  You can find an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Otherwise it might look something like this:

```
<table class="form-group">
    <tr>
        <th><h6><label for="Machine Name" class="col col-form-label">Machine Name</label></h6></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="col-12 col-md-2">
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtMachineName" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="256" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><h6><label for="serialNumber" class="col col-form-label">Serial Number</label></h6></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="serialNumber" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="256" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using tables just for cheesing layous is a bad practice...