# HTML: using an image as a button with text on top

Tags: html, css

I want to use an image as a button, and that I can do, however I wish to add text on top of the button and don't know how
This is how I want it to look.  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqjfx.png)  The image will be the whole and the text would be in the red part

How can I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
     <form  action=".html" method="LINK">
     <input type="image" src="cola.png" class="c11"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: You have to show us what you've attempted first because this is not a code writing service. We're here to help you identify the problem and correct it, not do your work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, totally forgot that

Comment: <form  action=".html" method="LINK">
 <input type="image" src="cola.png" class="c11"/>
 </form> 

@Waxi

Comment: @Mary_N Click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43348754/edit) link and include your code in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text over the image/button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324213/text-over-the-image-button)

Answer (score 0):

Image inputs are server side image maps. They are designed to let you click on an image and have the server identify *where* on the image you clicked.

If you want a regular button, with text, and a background image. Then use that:

```
<button>Your Text</button>

button {
    background-image: url(cola.png);
}
```

You may with to adjust the height, width, background colour and border of the image too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `input` as a button, use a `button` as a button, with the background set to the image you want, and because you're using a button, you can put text inside it easily.

```
<button type="submit">Text Goes Here</button>

button {
    background-image: url('cola.png');
}
```

Then you can change the styling on the button to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do this:

### Approach 1: Background image on div

**HTML**

```
<div class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    background: url('img.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('I was clicked');
}
```

### Approach 2: img tag with onclick

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgDiv">
  <img onclick="myFunction()" src="img.png" />
  <div>Click me</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgDiv {
    position: relative;
}
.imgDiv img, .imgDiv div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px; top: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('I was clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
     button {
       background-image: url("/images/driveicon.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       color: red;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="submit">Click Me!</button> 
</body>
</html>
```