# Text on the image in multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, css

I have simple CSS container and 3 different DIVs inside which aligned center. In each DIV, there is a image and text above of each image .  This so far working fine.

However, I like to put the text over the each image of possible (center inside the image). I tried to play with this instruction ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css)), but couldn't get it to work.  Please help!

Here is the CSS:

```
.containerCurve1 {
        width:90%; 
        border:0px solid black;
        text-align:center; 
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto; 
        background-color:white; 
        border-radius: 25px; 
        padding:20px;
        max-height: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        height:80vh;
    }

.imgLevel1
{
    margin-right:15px;
    width:300px; height:260px;
    background:#B2B4B3;
    padding:12px;
    border:2px solid #FFB652;       
}

.linkImage
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="containerCurve1">
<div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>            
    <a href="page1.html" class="linkImage">
        <span class="titlePicture">Picture 1</span><br>
        <IMG SRC="../project_img/Pic1.png" class="imgLevel1">
    </a>
</div>

<div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>
    <a href="page2.html" class="linkImage">
        <span class="titlePicture">Picture 2</span><br>
        <IMG SRC="../project_img/Pic1.png" class="imgLevel1" >
    </a>
</div>

<div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>           
    <a href="page3.html" class="linkImage">
        <span class="titlePicture">Picture 3</span><br>
        <IMG SRC="../project_img/Pic1.png" class="imgLevel1" >
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting the span below and using a negative top margin?

```css
.containerCurve1 {
        width:90%; 
        border:0px solid black;
        text-align:center; 
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto; 
        background-color:white; 
        border-radius: 25px; 
        padding:20px;
        max-height: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        height:80vh;
    }

.imgLevel1
{
    margin-right:15px;
    width:300px; height:260px;
    background:#B2B4B3;
    padding:12px;
    border:2px solid #FFB652;       
}

.linkImage
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.titlePicture
{
  display:block;
  margin-top:-150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerCurve1">
<div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>            
    <a href="page1.html" class="linkImage">
        <IMG SRC="../project_img/Pic1.png" class="imgLevel1"/>
        <span class="titlePicture">Picture 1</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>
    <a href="page2.html" class="linkImage">
       <IMG SRC="../project_img/Pic1.png" class="imgLevel1" />
       <span class="titlePicture">Picture 2</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;'>           
    <a href="page3.html" class="linkImage">
        <IMG SRC="../project_img/Pic1.png" class="imgLevel1" />
        <span class="titlePicture">Picture 1</span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: Click "full page" after you run the snippet.

Comment: I can see it works on your Full Page, but somehow when I put in my page, the negative top margin pushes everything up.  Maybe I am doing something wrong, I will continue playing with it...  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

There are lots of ways you could achieve this behavior.

One is changing the CSS property `position`of the wrapper to **relative** and of the title to **absolute**. Afterwards you place the title in the middle of the wrapper using `top: 50%` and `left: 50%`. After this you will notice that the element is not exactly centered, because it's own height and width are off the calculation. So we fix with the property `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`, which brings the element half of it's height up, and half it's width left. The result will be a vertically and horizontally centered element.

Another possibility would be using the CSS property `display: flex`. That would be easier because the entire layout is handled by the property. You could check more about this in [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

## Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
    .box {
      margin: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .box span {
      font-size: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .box.position {
      position: relative;
    }
    .box.position > span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .box.flex {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .box.table {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .google {
      width: 544px;
      height: 184px;
      background: url('https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="box position">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <span>this is centered</span>
  </div>

  <div class="box flex google">
    <span>this is also centered</span>
  </div>

  <div class="box table google">
    <span>and finally this</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Romulo.  This is very very nice solution.  It works on  both Mozilla and Chrome, but not IE11 unfortunately.  I would great if it could work for IE11 too.

Comment: @Milacay seriously? all the 3 examples are working fine in IE11 on my PC (windows 7).

Comment: yes I have IE-11 and Windows 7, I copied/pasted all your codes, then changed the images only. it is all un-align.   1st DIV, the picture on the lift and text floats to right. 2nd DIV text floats top of the picture...

Comment: oh, I opened it from my Windows 7 laptop it works, but on the Apache server, it is not display correctly.  Sorry for the confusion.  Do you have any idea why web server renders differently?