# How to Bring a h1 to top of the div?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML. In my HTML there is a `div` containing an image and an `h1` tag. Now the `h1` is coming under the `div`. How to position that `h1` on the center of the image?

```
<div class="headwrap">
    <div class="headimage"><img src="images/Header-image1.jpg">
    <h1 class="headtxt"> I Love Photography</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.headwrap {

    margin: 0;
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;


}

.headimage {

    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;

}

.headtxt {

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
    float: left;

}
```

Comment: since you posted no code, well... we can't help you. It'd only be guessing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position text over an image in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: relative` on the parent element and then put `position: absolute` on the H1 tag:

```
.headwrap {

margin: 0;
max-width: 1500px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;


}

.headimage {

max-width: 1500px;
width: 100%;

}

.headtxt {

position: absolute;
top: 0;

}
```