# how to make elements overlap to another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a design where some text of `id="text-field"` will overlap to `id="image-field"`. I have no idea how to do this, Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="text-field"> Some text </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="link-field"> Some link </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="image-field">Background Image </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position: absolute;`

Comment: You can learn about `position: absolute`.

Comment: first learn about position:absolute and z-index:value; then if you face any problem then ask :)

Comment: It's already answered in stackoverflow. Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small re-usable example it's a fairly common thing to do with css [here](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/xRoENG)

Here is a example

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.box__image {} .box__text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="box__text">
    Testing text
  </div>
</div>
```

Just a small explanation `position:relative` is used to keep `position:absolute` elements from going out of their containing div

Answer (score 0):

Using position properties you can ser postion of elements.

```
#image-field{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Research on postions property of css.You will get more idea 
[postion properties](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)