# Placing image over text

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to overlay **image** on **text** which is like a **pattern image**.

like we do in css for applying color with hex value

```
color: #ffffff;
```

**How it can be done?**

I'm trying to get pattern over text

[image: something like this]

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Didn't get your question

Comment: if my guess is right this question already has an answer here

Comment: @Naila you missed the "link"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position text over an image in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css)

Comment: @K.Daniek its the exact opposite of it

Comment: @K.Daniek   i'm trying to get image over text rather than text over image

Comment: It makes no sense then :3

Comment: hi please check answer 2 i will update my answer @om komawar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trying this

**[answer1](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageUnderText/)**

=============================================

**answer2**

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NzzkT/)**

**html**

```
<div id="container">  
  <h1>HAWAII</h1>
</div>
```

**css**

```
h1, p { margin: 0; }

#container {
    padding: 20px 20px 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
#container h1 {
    /* has same bg as #container */
    background: url(http://media.royalcaribbean.com/content/shared_assets/images/destinations/regions/hero/hawaii_01.jpg);

    font-size: 12em;
    font-family: impact;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 25px; /* padding + border of div */
    position: absolute; /* position at top left of #containter to sync bg */
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-fill-color: transparent; /* not yet supported */
    background-clip: text; /* not yet supported */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent; /* not yet supported */
    -moz-background-clip: text; /* not yet supported */
    /* text-shadow: 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); */
}
```

================

**answer3**

**css**

```
body {
    font: normal 16px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
}

/*
 * Caption component
 */
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Only the -webkit- prefix is required these days */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.caption__media {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -webkit-calc(-100% - 10px) );
            transform: translateY( calc(-100% - 10px) );

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/7GvV2/)**

Comment: I appreciate the answer but i'm trying to get image over text not text over image..

Comment: hi please check my answer2 may be usefull this answer @om komawar

Answer (score 4):

I have please check the code..

```css
h1 {
  
   background: url(http://www.lovethispic.com/uploaded_images/114180-Pink-Glitter-Pattern-.jpg) no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   font-size:80px
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jatin kalra