# How to resize image in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to **adjust image width and height** in bootstrap? I want image **height smaller** than it is appearing. How can I adjust its height? How I can write text on it? Here text is appearing under the image.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/blue-morpho-peleides-big- 
         butterfly-600w-407651284.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="butterfly">
          <figcaption class="figure=caption"> butterfly</figcaption>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position text over an image in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

In order to put text on your image you just need to create another `div` tag inside the `col` tag

You can set `width` and `height` for your image using html property `width` and `height` attribute with `img` tag

Here I have set `width` upto `80%` for your image

```
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/blue-morpho-peleides-big-butterfly-600w-407651284.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="butterfly" width="80%">
```

Here is the code of how to put text on your image.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<! -- HTML -- >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/blue-morpho-peleides-big- 
        butterfly-600w-407651284.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="butterfly">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/blue-morpho-peleides-big- 
          butterfly-600w-407651284.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="butterfly">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```